# What is anonymous and safe api to get bitcoin Exchange Rates?

Tags: api, exchange-rate, php

What is anonymous and safe api to get bitcoin Exchange Rates like BTC/USD and BTC/EUR without trace my ip ?

i used tor service, i search and found blockchain api contain Exchange Rates Feed

http://blockchain.info/ticker

is this secure means if i use this api, can blockchain trace my ip(tor) ?

and how can i use this api in php ?

and if anyone have others api provides bitcoin Exchange Rates Feed please tell me ?

thanks

Comment: thanks you but i ask about is api like blockchain can trace my ip when i get json file from it ?

Comment: Sure, but as you say you can use Tor with any API if you want to hide your IP address.

Comment: is there exist api anonymous and safe rather than blockchain api beside i use tor ?

Answer (score 1):

Any internet service, including an API, will be able to see the IP address the request originated from. It is reasonable to assume that at least in form of some log file, such information gets records by the API provider.

You have already indicated that you use TOR, which should, at least ideally, hide your real IP from the API service by effectively substituting the IP of the TOR exit node you happen to be using. If that achieves your goal depends on your motivation for hiding it in the first place. Note that TOR is not designed for, and likely not capable of, hiding your real IP from someone doing pervasive internet-wide wire sniffing (NSA, maybe?). Such an adversary would be able to simultaneously observe all traffic at all TOR nodes and correlate incoming and outgoing network activity of TOR nodes to potentially determine what your real IP address is.

You didn't specify why you want to hide your IP from whom exactly, and I'm having one of my unimaginative moments where I cannot come up with a likely scenario why it may be important for you to hide the fact that your computer was involved in looking up publicly accessible information where widespread interest for a whole variety of reasons exists anyways. Hence, I can't judge if for your application, this is sufficiently anonymous and safe (as you asked).

All bitcoin exchanges maintain their own public API for their exchange rate and usually lots of other data, even full order books. If you are happy with delayed third-party data, you can indeed also look at e.g. [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info) or [bitcoincharts.com](http://bitcoincharts.com/).

Comment: thanks you, i want hide my ip from site like blockchain that i used api to get exchange rate for bitcoin

Comment: That is something that using TOR and _not_ using any API keys or the like should achieve for you. Watch out for any stateful or identifying information your API client or underlying protocols may transmit, though, but most likely you'll achieve everything mentioned when using public http-based APIs that do not require API keys and to where you do not transmit cookies.

Comment: means if i use http to receive json file from blockchain.com to get last exchange rate of bitcoin it still blockchain.com  or any website provide can know my ip Although i used Tor or I2p

Comment: Well, potentially, if you have a leak for it. For example, on blockchain.info I currently see a cookie (probably from their cdn cloudflare.com, not from blockchain.info itself). With that they potentially already know all your requests came from the same source. Now if you ever make the mistake of transmitting the same cookie when not behind an anonymizing proxy, then, yes, they will know your IP. Shouldn't happen in theory and if you do everything right, but might easily happen in practice.